# c++ template function overloading

Tags: c++, templates

Below are lines from "the c++ programming language"

```
template<class T > T sqrt(T );
template<class T > complex<T> sqrt(complex<T>);
double sqrt(double);
void f(complex<double> z )
{
s q r t (2 ); // sqrt<int>(int)
sqrt(2.0) ; // sqrt(double)
sqrt(z) ; // sqrt<double>(complex<double>)
}
```

I dont understand why sqrt(z) ; calls `sqrt<double>(complex<double>)` can any body please explain.

Author says, 
`T sqrt<complex<T>>`  is more specialized than `T sqrt <T>` but there is a seperate declaration for `template<class T > complex<T> sqrt(complex<T>);` why not use that?

Comment: Sorry guys i did not understand sqrt<double>(complex<double>) represents complex<double>sqrt<complex<double>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the function used is the one you are talking about `sqrt<double>(complex<double>)` is an instance of the template `template <class T> complex<T> sqrt(complex<T>)`.

Your misunderstanding was in the signification of the template instance and not in the overloading process.

Answer (score 6):

In hindsight, it would have been easier if Bjarne would have written it as

```
template<class T> T sqrt(T);
template<class U> complex<U> sqrt(complex<U>);
double sqrt(double);
void f(complex<double> z )
{
    sqrt (2); // sqrt<int>(int)
    sqrt(2.0) ; // sqrt(double)
    sqrt(z) ; // sqrt<double>(complex<double>)
}
```

so you don't get confused by all the different T's. But the idea is simple; C++ finds the best match. There are three possible functions. The first two are perfect matches (no conversion needed) so the non-template version is ignored. Now, we have T=complex and U=double. Which version is chosen? Bjarne explains the second template is chosen here, because it's more specialized. This means that for any type U, there is a type `T=complex<U>` which makes the signatures of both templates identical.